# How can I use message queuing system for Kannel

Tags: architecture, queue, sms, kannel

I am currently developing SMS Service using Kannel as SMS Gateway. I have developed a rest service which will send messages to Kannel. I know this wont be enough to make it as a production level system. Can i make it more fault tolerant by using queues like ActiveMQ ? What additional components will be required to make it a better system. I don't have experience in making production level architecture hence I need your help. Any suggestion or pointers would be beneficial for me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kannel inherently implements message queueing. Generally a message is submitted to foobox where foo can be either sms, smpp or sql. When the message is received it is queued in kannels internal queue from where bearebox consumes, determines a suitable route via smsc configuration and forwards message to respective destination.

Here is the architecture design
http://www.kannel.org/download/1.3.2/arch-1.3.2/arch.html

Kannel SMSCs can be configured to handle message failures via simple configuration directives

For more information on kannel you might want to check user guide here
http://kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html